# TensorRT4: getCHW(const nvinfer1::Dims&): Assertion `d.nbDims >= 3' failed

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, resnet, tensorrt

**System information**

- What is the top-level directory of the model you are using: models/tree/master/research/tensorrt
- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): no
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): GNU/Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): via docker image nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:18.07-py3
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.18
- TensoRT version: 4.0.1.
- Bazel version (if compiling from source): n/a
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 9.0.176 / 7.1.4
- GPU model and memory: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB
- Exact command to reproduce:

`python3 tensorrt.py --frozen_graph=resnetv2_imagenet_frozen_graph.pb --image_file=image.jpg --native --fp32 --fp16 --int8 --output_dir=output_trt`

**Describe the problem**

I am running the example tensorrt.py via container image but it throws the error

```
python3: helpers.cpp:56: nvinfer1::DimsCHW nvinfer1::getCHW(const nvinfer1::Dims&): Assertion `d.nbDims >= 3' failed.".
```

The test worked fine without the flag `--int8`

**Source code / logs**

a lot of outputs when running susscesufully native graph, FP32 graph, and FP16 graph

```
Running INT8 graph

2018-08-14 19:29:51.458632: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:51] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8): 4
2018-08-14 19:29:52.261613: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:419] MULTIPLE tensorrt candidate conversion: 2
2018-08-14 19:29:52.539209: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3087] Max batch size= 128 max workspace size= 2123190784
2018-08-14 19:29:52.539473: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3101] finished op preparation
2018-08-14 19:29:52.539645: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3109] OK
2018-08-14 19:29:52.539655: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3110] finished op building
2018-08-14 19:29:52.568280: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3087] Max batch size= 128 max workspace size= 24292802
2018-08-14 19:29:52.568346: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3101] finished op preparation
2018-08-14 19:29:52.568374: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3109] OK
2018-08-14 19:29:52.568383: I tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc:3110] finished op building
INFO:tensorflow:Starting execution
2018-08-14 19:29:56.151230: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2018-08-14 19:29:56.151342: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-08-14 19:29:56.151354: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929] 0 1 2 3
2018-08-14 19:29:56.151380: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0: N Y Y Y
2018-08-14 19:29:56.151389: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 1: Y N Y Y
2018-08-14 19:29:56.151397: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 2: Y Y N Y
2018-08-14 19:29:56.151405: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 3: Y Y Y N
2018-08-14 19:29:56.152301: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU: 0 with 8080 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2018-08-14 19:29:56.152492: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU: 1 with 8080 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1c:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2018-08-14 19:29:56.152650: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU: 2 with 8080 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1d:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2018-08-14 19:29:56.152773: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU: 3 with 8080 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1e:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Warmup cycle
python3: helpers.cpp:56: nvinfer1::DimsCHW nvinfer1::getCHW(const nvinfer1::Dims&): Assertion `d.nbDims >= 3' failed.
```